# Is a single call to ExecuteNonQuery() atomic

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, transactions, transactionscope

Is a single call to ExecuteNonQuery() atomic or does it make sense to use Transactions if there are multiple sql statements in a single DbCommand?

See my example for clarification:

```
using (var ts = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (DbCommand lCmd = pConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        lCmd.CommandText = @"
            DELETE FROM ...;
            INSERT INTO ...";
      lCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    ts.Complete();
}
```

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` is not in itself atomic for multiple statements (those are just part of one batch), but you've already got a transaction because you've wrapped it all in a `TransactionScope`. (Assuming all that works correctly, of course -- bottom line is that `ExecuteNonQuery` does not itself add a transaction.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't ask for a transaction, you (mostly) don't get one. SQL Server wants everything in transactions and so, by default (with no other transaction management), for each separate *statement*, SQL Server will create a transaction and automatically commit it. So in your sample (if there was no `TransactionScope`), you'll get two separate transactions, both independently committed or rolled back (on error).

(Unless you've turned [`IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) on on that connection, in which case you'll get one transaction but you need an explicit `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` at the end. The only people I've found using this mode are people porting from Oracle and trying to minimize changes. I wouldn't recommend turning it on for greenfield work because it'll just confuse people used to SQL Server's defaults)

Answer (score 2):

It's not. SQL engine will treat this text as two separate instructions. `TransactionScope` is required (or any other form of transaction, i.e. implicit `BEGIN TRAN`-`COMMIT` in SQL text if you prefer).

Answer (score 1):

No, as the above answers say the command (as opposed to individual statements within the command) will not be run inside a transaction

Will be easy to verify

Sample code

```
create table t1
(
    Id int not null,
    Name text
)


using (var conn = new SqlConnection(...))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = @"
         insert into t1 values (1, 'abc');
         insert into t1 values (null, 'pqr');
    ";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The second statement will fail. But the first statement will execute and you'll have a row in the table.

Comment: No, I was careful to state that they *do* run inside transactions. Just ones that are managed entirely by SQL Server.

Comment: Also, as an aside, it's usually better to avoid using *positional* language ("above") to refer to other answers - better to link to them (use the share link below each to get a short link). There are 3 sort orders for answers (right hand side across from where it currently says "3 answers"), two of which are subject to change at any time (due to editing or voting)

Comment: Thanks @damien what I meant to say was the command itself is not atomic. Updated answer